# Locked myself out of my system...is there any way I can fix this?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, login

So, long story short, I did this the other day:

1.) Run the command:
`sudo nano /etc/pam.d/common-auth`.

2.) Add a line above the first non-commented line and add the following   code:
`auth required pam_tally2.so onerr=fail deny=3 unlock_time=600 audit`

Now, I cannot log into system. I didn't change any login details, but it keeps saying that my password is incorrect. This is a home Ubuntu installation hosting Plex, so nothing too important, but I'd like to avoid having to start fresh. Any tips?

Comment: Boot a version of Linux off a rescue disk, mount your current drive and edit this file to remove the offending line.   (see https://www.techradar.com/best/best-linux-repair-and-rescue-distros for some possible rescue disks)

Answer (score 0):

Generally you could follow the same instructions as "reset root password", only with `nano...` instead of `passwd...` at the very end.

- Reboot, select "rescue mode" if it's present in the GRUB boot menu (I remember Ubuntu used to have that), then choose the option to enter a shell.
- If there's no such choice in the menu, hit `e` at the regular menu item and add the option `1` or `rescue` (both activating the same single-user mode) at the end of the `linux` line. Press Ctrl-X to boot.

  This should boot you into a root-only shell that does not use PAM to log in. Edit the file to comment out the new line.
- If the single-user mode doesn't let you log in, instead add the option `systemd.debug-shell`. This will boot as usual (subject to other options) but will start an additional *password-less* shell on **tty9**.

  Press Alt-F9 (or Ctrl-Alt-F9 from within GUI environment) to switch to it and do your edits there. Switch back to tty1 or tty2 using the same keys to test.

Afterwards, 1) always have a "root" shell running while editing PAM (`sudo -s`, `sudo bash`, that kind); 2) install `pamtester` and use it to test your new PAM configuration without having to log out; 3) do not close that root shell until you're sure everything is okay.

```
# pamtester common-auth fred authenticate
# pamtester gdm fred authenticate acct_mgmt open_session close_session
```